# "Research Estimate" or "Estimate Research"

Tags: word-order, phrase-choice

My friend and I got into a small argument about which is the grammatically correct way to name the file of our estimation for how long it would take to research something, I tell him that it should be "Research Estimate" but he insist that "Estimate Research" is correct. Since I my English is self-taught for the most part I just felt that "Research Estimate" is the right one without being able to offer a clear explanation, so I want to know which one is the right one and why it is the right one.

Comment: It would either be a *research estimate* or an *estimate **of** research*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer comes down to two things: first, is it a noun or a verb phrase? That is, a thing, or a command? (Both "research" and "estimate" could be nouns or verbs.) It sounds like you're treating it as a thing.

Next, is it some research, or is it an estimate? You say it's an estimate, which means "research" is modifying "estimate", acting like an adjective would. Since we're using English, the modifier/adjective comes first (in general), so "Research Estimate" is correct.